# grails test-app without compile

Tags: grails

Is it possible to to run a grails test-app without compiling?
Example:
Step 1:
grails test-app
This step compiles everything and runs the test.
Step 2:
grails test-app [WITHOUT COMPILING]

Is there an chance to start the second test-app run without a second compiling, when no source code was changed?

Thanks
  Frafu

Answer (score 3):

Grails Interactive mode should get what you want.

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/interactive.html

Comment: Grails interactive was giving me perm gen exception. But it is good enough for first few runs.